# Use a .csv as an input for API

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, rest

I have an API that uses the post method to update some data from the database. This API right now only allows a single update each time is called, that means if you want to update many products, you have to do it one by one.

Example:

```
payload = json.dumps({
  "supplierReference": "XX23", 
    "products" :[{
        "Distributor": "",
        "Description": "",
        "Price": ""
        "Brand": "",
    }    ]
}
```

I need to undestand if is possible and if so, how to use a .csv file or .xlsx file as an input to the API call to update many products at once, by calling the API several times (as many times as the lines).

The file's something like this:

[image]

This is how my code is:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import json_normalize
import requests
import json

# Authentication part of the code

url = "https://api-gateway.com/api"

headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': 'Bearer '+ data['access_token'],
}

payload = json.dumps({
  "supplierReference": "XX23", 
    "products" :[{
  "Distributor": input("Enter Distributor: "), 
  "Description": input("Enter Description: "),
  "Price": input("Enter Price: "),
  "Brand": input("Enter Brand: ")
})

response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=payload, verify=True)

response_data = json.loads(response.text)
```

Comment: Your code does not create the JSON structure provided in the example. Also the example has a list of products, seems like adding more might work.

Comment: Yes, you can. I think that you are trying to post to a 3rd party api that does not have batch endpoints and only accepts JSON. Just load the CSV with pandas, and write a function that transforms a series (row) into a compliant api json. Loop for every row and post all the rows... Take into account that the API might have rate limits.

Comment: @ivvija You are correct. I fixed it the example.

Comment: Using CSV is asking for trouble, because it's not well specified or structured. You'll inevitably run into cases that will make you tear your hair out. Stick with JSON.

Comment: @MarkRansom Do you have any other suggestion ? Because this file will be provided by the end-user, so I guess it must be on tabular form. I'm afraid JSON will be a little bit of a struggle for them.

Comment: If you're stuck with CSV then I'd recommend using Python's [`csv` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) and agreeing on the details of a standardized format, such as the [RFC 4180](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4180.html) recommended there.  That will minimize the hair pulling.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are looking for something like this?

```
with open(CSV_FILE, "r") as csv_f:
    next(csv_f)
    for line in csv_f:
        values = line.strip().split(",") #if ',' is the separator
        payload = {
            "Reference": values[0],
            "Distributor": values[1],
            "Description": values[2],
            "Price": values[3],
            "Brand": values[4]
        }
        response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=payload, verify=True)
        response_data = json.loads(response.text)
```

Comment: Assuming the code you provided at the bottom works

Comment: But I guess this will only work if you send only one "line", right ?
I need to send many lines and get as many requests as the number of lines!

Comment: @CED the lines at the end are part of a `for` loop and will execute once per line.  But this is exactly the way of parsing a CSV that I warned you against.

Answer (score 1):

Verify that the API you are talking to doesn't support JSON lists. If not, you will have to do it in a loop with each item creating a new request. Or you can  make use of asynchronous requests with aiohttp:

```py
import asyncio
import aiohttp

url = "https://api-gateway.com/api"
my_data = ['{...}', '{...}', '{...}'] # imagine an Iterable containing your JSON data

async def send_post_request(session, url, data):
    async with session.post(url, data=data) as response:
        response_text = await response.text()
        print(f"Response from {url}: {response_text}")

async def main():
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        tasks = [asyncio.create_task(send_post_request(session, url, item)) for item in my_data]
    await asyncio.gather(*tasks)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

Doing it asynchronously like that will most likely make it quite fast, depending on the fact if the API self can process the requests in parallel.
You might surpass the rate limit of the API if you send too many requests at the same time.

Comment: I had made a mistake within my code and didn't include the list inside the JSON, I fixed it!

Comment: I'm getting a syntax errors but don't know where

Comment: thanks for the comment: `async with` needs the next line to be indented. Fixed it

Comment: Now I'm getting "RuntimeError: asyncio.run() cannot be called from a running event loop"

Comment: This only means the event loop has been already created somewhere else for the thread in which this code runs. If you are using jupyter notebook, there is already an event loop so do only `await main()` instead of creating the new loop with `asyncio.run`

Comment: I did replace the asyncio.run but I'm getting RuntimeError: Session is closed. I'm a little bit confused how to handle it. 

async def send_post_request(session, url, data):
    async with session.post(url, data=data) as response:
        response_text = await response.text()
        print(f"Response from {url}: {response_text}")

async def main():
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        tasks = [asyncio.create_task(send_post_request(session, url, item)) for item in my_data]
    await asyncio.gather(*tasks)

await main()

Comment: And yes, I'm using Jupyer currently, but this code will run on a executable when it's completed.

Comment: are you using the session out of the context of the `async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session`?

Comment: I don't think so, the only thing I'm doing before this piece of code is to import my .csv and transform it into json and include the headers in the request... my_data = pd.read_csv(filedialog.askopenfilename(), sep=',')

my_data = my_data.to_json(orient='records')

async def send_post_request(session, url, data):
    async with session.post(url, headers=headers, data=data) as response: